# ¿como impedir que recargue una página?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

Estoy haciendo un proceso de compra en Django y me he dado cuenta de que al recargar realiza una nueva compra.

ahora mismo tengo este código:

```
def comprar(request,producto,stock):
    if request.POST:
        if form.is_valid():
            ...
            proceso compra
            ...
            return render(request, 'intranet/confirmacion_comprar.html',
            {'resultado':resultado,'perfil':perfil,'producto':producto,'foto':foto[0],
            'gastos_envio':comision.gastos_envio,'total':total})
    return redirect('proceso-compra',slug=producto.slug)
```

Comment: Después del proceso que hagas con los datos del form, puedes limpiar las variables POST para que no vuelva a insertar el registro en caso de F5, sería así: $_POST = array();

Comment: Estoy utilizando Django, no existe $_POST, eso es en PHP y el POST en Django es inmutable.

Comment: Cierto, se me coló, aún así tienes request.POST

Comment: He visto que una posible forma es volver a enviar el formulario vacío. request.POST no es posible de modificar, solo puedo copiarlo en una segunda variable y esta si puedo modificar la respuesta.

Comment: Entonces solo se me ocurre que antes del insert, hagas un select para ver si ya existe el registro y en caso afirmativo, no hacer el insert.